# Presentation software showing map of slides?

Tags: open-source, presentation

*Representing slides as `[ ]`*

I am presenting a pipeline within a slideshow, I want to show all the slides like this at the beginning and end of my presentation:

```
[ ] -> [ ] -> [ ] -> [ ] -> [ ]
```

Is there an open-source, free or paid program supports this functionality without watermarking their brand?

Comment: Currently checking out [hovercraft](http://regebro.github.io/hovercraft)

Comment: It MUST be Open Source (whether gratis or paid), or may it also be freeware/proprietary?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: It doesn't have to be open-source; but that is preferred.

Comment: Isn't taking a screenshot from Powerpoint slide sorter view sufficient for the job? You can zoom it as you need (Ctrl+MouseWheel) to get all the slides to one screen before taking a screenshot.

Comment: I don't want a screenshot; I want a dynamic open-source presentation solution. Arrows showing directions between slides is also not present in that software.

Comment: I am not sure why you insist on an Open Source. Do you want to modify the code? Or you are referring to a **Free** Program?

Comment: Yes, I want to modify the code

Comment: Then why say "`Is there an open-source, free or paid program`"? You are unlikely to get code with a paid program. How important is the code to you? It is difficult to answer your question unless we know.

Comment: Having the code is greatly preferred, as I'd like to integrate it into other open-source software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`reveal.js`](https://revealjs.com/) and [`impress.js`](https://impress.js.org/#/overview) both are solutions to author your presentations in a self-hosted `html w/ js` file/folder.

`reval.js` also has an [online editor](https://slides.com/)

They have the ability to zoom-in and zoom-out to display the slide-desk similar to what you requested.

Both are FOSS.

Comment: 7 years late but yeah impress.js was what I was seeking

Comment: Funny enough, I discovered this site 7 years later :) The software I actually discovered about 6 years ago, so still not on time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply draw that element and put it on any presentation program at the beginning or end.

Similar to Prezi is fokusky http://focusky.com/ so at the end you can zoom out and show all the slides.

It also has an automated progress bar.

It is not Open Source but has a free version.